# Firebase Firestore: use .where() with a subcollection

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I want to do something like this:

```
firestore().collection('users').collection("account").where('email', '==', "example@gmail.com").get();
```

I want to get user's data among users who has a specific email. But the problem here is that the email is in a subCollection.
How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the problem, in the current SDKs, you can't do this. you have to specify a full path, i.e :

```
collection1->doc->collection2.where(..etc
```

Would advise to move this `key \email` to the doc in the first collection if it's that important. Otherwise, you have to run multiple chained queries. Or fetch all the docs in collection#1, then for each doc, run your `where` query on every one of those docs and look into their subcollections, but it'll cost you lots of reads. Consider restructuring your data.